# Where do I add events in Laravel 5.1 when user registers

Tags: php, events, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have an `Event::fire();` on `getRegister();` in `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php`

But I know this is not the correct location for it:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    Event::fire(new UserWasRegistered(Auth::id()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

How I add the event so it's not in Illuminate and in AuthController?

Edit: The event is working perfectly. I just need to know which location is best to fire it?

Comment: You can do it in `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you elaborate? I already listen for the Event there: https://github.com/jackbarham/sandbox/blob/master/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this:

```
protected $listen = [
    UserWasRegistered::class => [
        SendActivationEmail::class,
        CreateNewModel::class,
    ],
];
```

Now just go to your console/command prompt and run `php artisan event:generate` then go to `App\Events` and `App\Listeners` folder and find the appropriate classes and implement as you need, because `Laravel` will generate those classes for you.

**Update:**
Actually, your question was not clear, anyways. You should not modify that `trait` instead you can use that trait in any class and use the methods of that trait. In This case, you can implement your custom Registration. To do this, just use the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` and override the `postregister` method:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

// ...

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    // Other methods ...

    public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        // Do the coding here
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

        // Fire Event Here...

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());

    }
}
```

In this controller `(App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController)` which you may use to implement your custom `postRegister` method.

Comment: Thanks, I have already done that. Event is working perfectly. However, I need the event to fire when the User registers (it sends an activation email). At the moment I have it firing in `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php` (shown above) and need to move it to somewhere in App/ and not sure where or to achieve it?

Comment: You can fire the event from `controller` which listens to your user registration route.

Comment: Thanks, which controller? Apologies I'm new to this. Do you have a quick example?

Comment: Yeah I figured that out - I just copied the whole method over. Just as a side not you also need to namespace `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of `AuthController`. Thanks for your help, I've marked as answered :)

Comment: Thanks and yes I've omitted the `use` statements but indicated missing chunks of code using `...` to make you/user attention. All the best @JackBarham :-)